# Buying stocks after a successful but excessively diluting seasoned offering

Tags: stocks, investing, investment-strategies

I regularly see companies offering seasoned equity with a subscription right and whose capital increase is successful but whose stock still dips a few days after below the rate of the subscription right. In this case, is there any rational to buy this stock once it dipped? My reasoning is the following:

- On a purely financial aspect, a successful capital increase is a healthy sign for the future of the company
- On a psychological aspect, many shareholders bought their new shares at the rate of the subscription right and will thus be averse to selling below this rate, strengthening the stock that I bought below this rate until it reaches it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The past is the past. What matters is how strongly you believe that class of that stock is going to increase in value after you buy it, by how much, in how much time, compared to other possible investment and savings choices.

Comment: Then let me rephrase: how good and trustworthy of an indicator the case that I described is for the future of the stock?

Comment: In isolation, it isn't. Short-term moves are close to meaningless. If you believe the equity will gain value from where it is now before you need to sell it, a dip can even be considered a buying opportunity. If you don't believe that, you probably shouldn't be buying that equity.